# Spanish for “newspaper”

Tags: vocabulario, méxico

What is the difference between a **periódico** and a **diario**? If both mean exactly the same thing, which one is preferred in regular colloquial usage in Mexico vs. other Spanish-speaking countries?

Comment: A Mexican is the only one can answer the question, in Cuba my country we never use `diario`, we use `periódico ` or `prensa escrita` in a very formal environment.

Comment: In Spain, strictly speaking, a `periódico` is a newspaper published periodically, and a `diario` is a `periódico` published daily. But in reality we use them interchangeably, and in fact, `periódico` is much more used, almost always meaning `diario`.

Comment: @Chewie please promote to full answer.

Comment: Just to add that in Colombia the patter of the reported use is the same.  While technically _«periódico»_ is any periodic paper, and _«diario»_ is a daily paper, the common word is almost always _«periódico»_ for any newspaper, usually a daily newspaper.  _«Diario»_ is still the name use in certain newspapers' names or mottoes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"**Periódico**" in México. I live here.

Comment: Exacto. Aunque posiblemente cualquiera en México entienda a que te refieres si dices "diario", es mucho mas común escuchar "ir a comprar el periódico" o "lo leí en el periódico" que usando "diario".

Answer (score 5):

**Diario** is the common word, by far, in Argentina.

**Periódico** is understood here as a formal (or "foreign") synonym. Everyone understands it, no one uses it.

Strictly speaking, "diario" is more restricted in meaning (*daily* newspaper), but common usage does not respect that much anymore - one could even hear about a "diario semanal".

Answer (score 2):

**Periódico** is the common word to say in Spain.

It has some [sinonyms](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/peri%C3%B3dico), including **diario**:

> diario, boletín, gaceta, noticiero, rotativo

Mainly are the same, but **Diario** is a **Periódico** published daily.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the word "periódico" for newspaper.

Actually in some cases it can be used as just simply "paper" (not as in plain regular paper that you write with).

> "periódico vespertino" is the "evening paper"

Or

> "Leí el periódico de punta a cabo" which means "[I] read the paper from cover to cover".

Diario can mean "every day" (which I am certain is not what you mean), "daily", or "diary".

If the conversation is about some text and I hear the word, "diaro", I think of a "diary". I personally do not use the diaro to describe a "newspaper".

I hope this helps.